# maven surefire plugin is not executing runners in parallel

Tags: java

I have set up `maven-surefire-plugin` in `POM.xml`.
Ideally as per the help I got over the internet for using these plugin, my set up should run cucumber Runner files in parallel but they are always getting executed sequentially.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Using JUnit or TestNG ? And please share complete pom.xml for better understanding.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn` when you run your maven goals? What is the output you get with the `-X` flag for debugging? It might have some useful information while executing the goals. Please [edit] your question with the complete POM file and the output of the `mvn (-X)` command.